# Finding index and column number of strings in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, find, location

I have a dataframe (multiple columns) and I want to find the exact (numerical) location in the dataframe of certain strings. With location I mean I want to know both it's row number as well as it's column number (not column name).

Let's make an example with the following dataframe `df`:

```
hi      apple   fine
right   yes     okay
maybe   apple   no
```

I want to find the location of all apples so I want to know there is an `apple` on row 0 column 1 and an `apple` on row 2 column 1.

How can I find these numbers?

I started with looking for all places where the condition is fulfilled that that element contains indeed the string I'm looking for, with:

```
df[df=='apple']
```

This is fine but how do I get the location of all `True`?
I tried this `df.index[df=='apple'].tolist()` but it gives an error because there are multiple columns. I understand I can solve this by running a for loop over all columns but wondering if there is something more straightforward. Also `str.find()` doesn't give me the column number. I also looked into `get_loc` but this only seemed to work for indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere`:

```py
print(np.argwhere(df.values == "apple"))
```

Prints:

```py
[[0 1]
 [2 1]]
```

---

As a list:

```py
print(np.argwhere(df.values == "apple").tolist())
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 1]]
```